# compile opengl with mingw in linux

Tags: linux, opengl, compilation, mingw

i wanted to ask how can i compile opengl with mingw. (in linux)
For c++ files i know i can do this :

i586-mingw32msvc-g++  main.cpp -o main.exe

and its ok.

If i try it with opengl project ,it gives me errors ,like :
glutInit’ was not declared in this scope   etc..

I copied glut.h ,glx.h,freeglut.h in the /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include/GL 
but nothing happend.

Comment: did you `#include` them?

Comment: In file included from main.c:11:
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.4.4/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/include/GL/glut.h:17:26: error: freeglut_std.h: It doesn't exist
In file included from main.c:13:
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.4.4/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/include/GL/glx.h:38:22: error: X11/Xlib.h: It doesn't exist
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.4.4/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/include/GL/glx.h:39:23: error: X11/Xutil.h: It doesn't exist
In file included from main.c:13:
...........and so on

Comment: And in the end:main.c:15:58: error: X11/X.h: It doesn't exist
main.c:16:24: error: X11/keysym.h: It doesn't exist
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:77: error: ‘GLUT_SINGLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:77: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
main.c:77: error: for each function it appears in.)
main.c:77: error: ‘GLUT_RGB’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: I found it(not with mingw) : $ gcc -o draw.exe main.c -lGL -lGLU -lglut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to link GLUT.

```
i586-mingw32msvc-g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -lglut
```

The line above assumes glut is installed an in the compiler search path.  Try that and let us know how that works out for you.

Comment: He's cross-compiling from Linux to Win32 through Wine.  Where did he install the compiled glut lib before linking it?  There doesn't seem to be a convention for where to install cross-compiled libs...some put them under /usr/local ...  I guess I'll open a new question...